# How do I report a bug when launchpad does not work?

Tags: package-management, launchpad

I found a bug in engrampa. When I tried to report it I got to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/engrampa/+filebug/d65ee956-654a-11ed-99a1-40a8f0305cb4.

After an hour, the bug data was still not processed.

I tried a second time. Same results.

This is what happens when children try to code.

P.S. The engrampa bug is that when I try to open a .txt file, it checks to see if a Pluma window is open. If one is, it closes all open tabs, then opens a tab with the specified files. The correct behavior is not to close and tabs.

Comment: Have you tried just filing the bug online (*using web browser*), and then post-filing you add the system details from the impacted system using `apport-collect` (with the bug ID of the browser reported bug report).  *Your alternative is to go online & seek help from the launchpad team; I usually use iRC for this*

Comment: Try the built-in application on all Ubuntu systems: `ubuntu-bug engrampa`, which will then ask you a few questions and then construct the Launchpad bug for you. "closing all tabs" suggests a crash. Check for any .crash files in /var/crash corresponding to the date/time of one of your attempts. If there is a .crash file, attach it to the bug report.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to report a bug about Launchpad itself, you can file a bug on the Launchpad project within Launchpad: https://launchpad.net/launchpad

For your particular case, I would wait for a few hours and try again. Sometimes, systems get overloaded.